# Decode binary QR Code data with javascript

Tags: javascript, qr-code

I have an array with 0/1 for white and black (I can change this as needed) of a QR code. Each part of the array is a Y line of the QR Code.

I need to write something that can decode that QR Code data into something usable, it can be many different types of QR codes so I need to be able to detect which type it is as well.

Can this be done with pure javascript? I can't run JQuery.

it looks like this (top two of 40ish lines), but I'm generating it from a string with a for loop so I can turn it into anything else.

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: "Each part of the array is a Y line" not sure to get it. x. Also what output do you want ?If each value represents a pixel (or a block), and that you do know the x number of pixels (width), you could generate an image from this using canvas ImageData.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with zxing, with [jsqrcode](https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode) - the javascript implementation of zxing.

At first you have to save your data in a BinaryMatrix, then decode it.

```
var bitMatrix = new BitMatrix(width);
bitMatrix.clear();

//for each black pixel
bitMatrix.flip(y,x);

var decoded = Decoder.decode(bitMatrix);

var decodedString = "";

for (var i = 0; i < decoded.length; i++) {
    var currentWord = decoded[i];
    for(var j = 0; i < currentWord.length; j++)
    {
        result += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(currentWord[i]));
    }   
}
```

*decoded* then contains one or more ascii byte-array. Just run the loop for all arrays in decoded.
*result* then holds a string containing the original string from the qr-code.

This should in theory work for all types supported by zxing, but I only tested it with qr-codes.

Answer (score -1):

These are the methodes:
`toString(2)` to convert to a binary string.

or `parseInt(input,10)` if you know the input should be decimal.

To go from binary to text, use `parseInt(input,2).toString(10)`.

Comment: I don't think this is binary data, but I may get the question wrong.

Comment: Turing the string into binary data isn't really the problem I'm trying to solve. I'm trying to decode the QR string into what ever it says.